# Awk - unterminated regex

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I am writing a shell script which needs to pull values out of a text file which looks like this:

```
app.full.name /warfilelocation/ warfilename
```

My shell script will be iterating over a list of application names and pulling out either the location or name using AWK.  I have tested doing this on the command line using the following:
    awk "\$1 ~/app.full.name/ { print $2 }" applications.txt

which returns what I would expect however when i put this in a shell script I start having issues.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function get_location() {
        local application=$1
        awk "\$1 ~/^$application/ { print \$2 }"  applications.txt 
}
```

But when i call this function i get the following error:

```
awk: $1 ~/^app.full.name
awk:      ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: app.full.name
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:2: app.full.name/ { print $2 }
awk: cmd. line:2:    ^ syntax error
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong here.  I presume I am not escaping the variable correct but no matter what i try it doesnt seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you calling the function? What is the value of application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this approach to make awk recognize shell variables:

```
awk -v "v1=$VAR1" -v "v2=$VAR2" '{print v1, v2}' input_file
```

**Update**

```
$ cat input
tinky-winky
dipsy
laa-laa
noo-noo
po

$ teletubby='po'

$ awk -v "regexp=$teletubby" '$0 ~ regexp' input
po
```

Note that *anything* could go into the shell-variable,
even a full-blown regexp, e.g `^d.*y`. Just make sure to use single-quotes
to prevent the shell from doing any expansion.

Comment: he wants to fill the variable value into Regex. not just print it out

Comment: @Kent - just stating that `-v` allows you to use a shell variable in a awk script. Then that variable can be used as a regexp in a `match()` function; but that part I left out...

Comment: i think the point is match(). since the variable (by -v) cannot be used in  awk matching check like ($x~/here/ ). at least I don't know how to use in this case. :)

Comment: @Kent - see updated answer, no need to use the match function

Comment: thanks, I was always fighting with the two slashes. :D great to know how to use var in regex. +1

Answer (score 0):

The error messages seem to indicate that there is a stray newline at the end of $application, which gives the "line 2" error messages.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing, he wants to test for the first field, that is $1 ~ /^app/

Comment: Oh, thanks, didn't realize this is actual awk syntax. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

see this: using awk match() function

```
kent$  app=app.ful
kent$  echo "app.full.name /warfilelocation/ warfilename"|awk -v a=$app '{if(match($1,a))print $2}' 
/warfilelocation/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing exactly the value of $application, but it seems like you have a strange character in $application, such as a " or a / or something like that.

```
$ export application=foo/bar
$ awk "\$1 ~/^$application/ { print \$1 }"
gawk: cmd. line:1: $1 ~/^foo/bar/ { print $1 }
gawk: cmd. line:1:                ^ parse error
```

I would look at the exact value that you have in $application, and if it contains a /, escape it.

One way to do this would be to use:

```
$ export application=`echo foo/bar | sed -e 's;/;\\\\/;g'`
$ awk "\$1 ~/^$application/ { print \$1 }"
```